# How to return results from stored procedure as a List?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Previously this worked well and recently the line stop working. This code uses the DB context to run a procedure and return it in List format. For some reason I am not seeing the error, I just see the action fail because it is not executing.

I ran the stored procedure in SQL Server and see the desired results, just not seeing it happening from the application layer.

```
[Http.Route("postsearch")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostSearch(SearchInputDTO srequest)
{
   var searchString = srequest.SearchValue.ToString();            
   List<output> seResult = new List<output>(_output.searchLog(searchString)); /*This line stopped working*/
   return Ok(seResult);
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
SET FMTONLY OFF
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[searchLog]
    @searchValue VARCHAR(150)
AS
    SELECT *  
    FROM [dbo].[output]
    WHERE CONTAINS (*, @searchValue)
```

Implementation in Entity Framework

```
public virtual int searchLog(string searchValue)
{
    var searchValueParameter = searchValue != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("searchValue", searchValue) :
            new ObjectParameter("searchValue", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("searchLog", searchValueParameter);
}
```

This should return the rows from the query.

Comment: Your problem description is very vague. I don't know what you might mean by "I see if fail." There is probably nothing wrong with the code if it worked before, so you have given us pretty much nothing to go on of any substance.

Comment: The Action returns an internal error.

Comment: You need to determine what the internal error is, e.g. by logging the exception.

Comment: Message = "Non-negative number required.\r\nParameter name: capacity" I am not sure what that error is since it either returns rows or null

Comment: C# thinks you are calling [this constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Int32_) with an integer. I suspect you wish to call [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__) instead. You didn't provide the implementation for `searchLog()` so I don't know why you're getting an integer instead of an IEnumerable.

Comment: oh, I updated the question a while back with the SQL stored proc

Comment: `searchLog()` is a c# method, not a SQL Server stored procedure. We need to see the c# code for that.

Comment: I added the implementation code for it above earlier also.

Comment: Oh I see. You didn't include the method declaration at the top, which would have been very helpful. [ExecuteFunction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executefunction?view=netframework-4.8) returns an integer that indicates the number of rows returned. It appears that number is `0`, explaining the error. It may have been `1` or more before (e.g. if the database changed) which is why it "worked" before, although I don't see how it could ever have returned any rows.

Comment: Any thoughts on what to edit in order to get the rows?

Comment: Can you post the  signature definition for `searchLog`?

Comment: @JohnWu I have been searching how to do that and no success. Could I get some guidance on this?

Answer (score 1):

The Solution I found was to modify the output of the stored procedure in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the new instance of the list and just have it like this

```
List<output> seResult = _output.searchLog(searchString);
```

Update stored proc to

```
@searchValue varchar(150)

AS

BEGIN

SELECT
  [ColumnName1]
  ,[ColumnName2] ...etc...
FROM [dbo].[output]
WHERE CONTAINS (*,@searchValue) 

END
```

Comment: I tried that and receive an error stating cannot convert int to List.

Comment: Can I see your searchLog method?

Comment: I made an edit to the original post which now shows it.

Comment: I see your stored proc, but i don't see your searchLog method.what ORM are you using? and how are you hitting that stored procedure. can you do me a favor and right click on .searchLog and click "Go To Implementation"

Comment: I am using Entity framework and access the stored proc via DB context.

Comment: the searchLog method is returning an int so.... try changing List<output> to List<int>

Comment: Is there something that I can change in the stored proc in order to get a list?

Comment: Try updating your stored proc and instead of select * ... select every column you need (literally, type out all the columns) .. then go to your edmx and update the stored proc, should give you a model called searchLog_Result then create a using DbContext, you can return a list

Comment: aslso... in your stored proc... wrap your query inside a  'BEGIN' and an 'END'

Comment: No success with that approach.